# Rubymine not recognizing installed gems

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems, rubymine

My Ruby project is not recognizing the gem I just installed in Terminal. The gem is also not showing up in external libraries.

[image: JetBrains Workspace Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is fixed in [RubyMine 5.0](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/download/index.html)